# Remove duplicates from python csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a csv file in python and the column names are a,b,c,d,f and data is below

```
                  a,b,c,d,f
                  ab1,ef1,hi1,kl1,Y
                  ab2,ef2,hi2,kl2,N
                  ab3,ef3,hi1,kl3,Y
                  ab4,ef4,hi2,kl4,N
                  ab5,ef5,hi3,kl5,Y
                  ab6,ef6,hi4,kl6,N
```

First I want to filter the data where column f is N and the get unique values of column c and the output should have only column c data like below:

```
                       hi2
                       hi4
```

My code is as below:

```
          with open(input_txt) as f,open(output_txt, 'w') as outfile:

               reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
               writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = '|')
                for row in reader:
                   my_row = []
                   if row['f'] == "N":
                       my_row.append(row['c'])
                       writer.writerow(my_row)
```

With this code i am not able to eliminate duplicates and getting the below output.

```
                                 hi2
                                 hi2
                                 hi4
```

I tried with set and not able to achieve and appreciate your help if there is any other way to eliminate the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has direct read function for csv files. Which you can use. Moreover its also easier to accomplish what you are after using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input_file.txt')
df.loc[df.f=='N','c'].unique()
```

If you wish to write it in a file, you can do as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input_file.txt')
with open('output_file.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(list(df.loc[df.f=='N','c'].unique())))
```

Comment: This would run the unique clause on all rows, not just on C, if memory serves. As in: It checks if the entire row is unique in comparison to others.

Comment: Hey @Dustin its fixed! but what do you meant by if memory serves? If 'c' is there, it would drop duplicates based on 'c' else on the basis of whole row.

Comment: With the fix it is all fine! Didn't even know you can just put a comma between it and it will filter

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a module called pandas. It is very popular, especially in Data Science and transforming data.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"inputpath.csv")
df = df[df["f"] == "N"] # filter F for N
df = df[["C"]] # might be possible with only one pair of []. Only keep column C
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset="C") # explains itself, doesn't it!
df.to_csv(r"outputpath.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `set`  on the last step

```
In [1]: d = {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,}   # this a set, not a dictionary.

In [2]: d
Out[2]: {1, 2, 3}
```

ok, just to have more details

```
In [5]: my_set = set()

In [6]: my_set.add(2)

In [7]: my_set
Out[7]: {2}

In [8]: my_set.add(3)

In [9]: my_set
Out[9]: {2, 3}

In [10]: my_set.add(2)

In [11]: my_set
Out[11]: {2, 3}

In [12]:
```